# jq equivalent in python

Tags: python, arrays, json, jq

```
cat * | jq '.cis[].properties.cloud_vm_display_name' | grep -v null
```

"azuXXXXX"
"azuXXXXX"
"azuXXXXXX"
"azuXXXXXX"

Need to extract cloud VM name from multiple json files where the array number is different in every file.

```
a = data1['cis'][0]['properties']['TenantsUses'][0]
print(a)
b = data1['cis'][]['properties']['cloud_vm_display_name']
```

```
File "<stdin>", line 17
b = data1['cis'][]['properties']['cloud_vm_display_name']
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

print(a) is providing correct output but the value [] for variable b is not known, need your support in finding the output.

To find the VM name from various json files which are generated for different servers.

Comment: There is no magic syntax here, you need some kind of iteration over the `['cis']` data to find a match

Comment: For the best possible answer, you could include a small json file that is representative for the real one in the question and also provide the expected output.

Comment: So you want to ignore vm display names such as "anulled" or "nullified"? But python has loops, so use them.

Answer (score 0):

Python has loops (and list comprehensions) that can be used here.

```
b = []
for cis in data1['cis']:
  name = cis['properties']['cloud_vm_display_name']
  if not 'null' in name:
    b.append(name)
print(b)
```

With a list comprehension:

```
b = [cis['properties']['cloud_vm_display_name'] for cis in data1['cis'] if not 'null' in cis['properties']['cloud_vm_display_name']]
```

or a generator expression to prepare the data and a list comprehension to filter the desired names:

```
names = (cis['properties']['cloud_vm_display_name'] for cis in data1['cis'])
b = [name for name in names if not 'null' in name]
```

Note that this implements the same behavior as your `grep` example: any name that contains null anywhere (e.g. "nullified" or "anulled"), will not be part of the resulting list. You probably meant `grep -vx` or `name == 'null'`, respectively. Even better, don't use grep at all, but filter with jq directly: `.cis[].properties.cloud_vm_display_name | values`.